# Invoice number auto increment

Tags: vb.net, auto-increment, increment

```
Invoice Number = Now.Year & Now.Month & ?????
```

how can i add 5 digits that auto increment when the form loads?

> Expected OUTPUT
>
> 20120100001
>
> 20120100002

Now.Month Problems#

when the month is one digit invoice will be 10 digits while when it is two digits invoice will be 12 digits?

OUTPUT

> 20121?????

EXPECTED OUTPUT

> 201201?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Now.Month.ToString("00")`.

```
Dim str = DateTime.Now.Year & DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("00")
```

Try this,

```
Sub Main()
    For i = 1 To 12
        Console.WriteLine(GetAutonumber(i))
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetAutonumber(no As Integer) As String
    Dim strNum = no.ToString()
    Dim str = DateTime.Now.Year & DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("00") & New String("0", 5 - strNum.Length) & strNum
    Return str
End Function
```

Comment: I just want to add that when the invoiceNumber is incremented the last value of it was saved in mysql database? how can i do that?

-Thank you